# Angularjs: Select ng-options right way

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

For the select tag with angularjs i'm doing:

```
<select ng-init="getdata()" data-ng-model="ob.id" 
        data-ng-options="level.id as level.desc for level in levels" 
        data-ng-selected="ob.id == level.id"> 
        <option value="0">default...</option>
</select>
```

... but is this the right way because there are so many other ways on the web?
getdata() gets $scope.levels array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write ng-selected, it's not necessary. Also ng-init should just be used in really specific cases ([nginit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)) so as OZ mentioned it'd better to call getData() from the controller.

```
<select data-ng-model="ob.id" 
        data-ng-options="level.id as level.desc for level in levels"> 
    <option value="0">default...</option>
</select>
```

Other than that the select looks correct.

Comment: In fact the ng-init is just for the question, but i didn't know that there's no need for the ng-selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid binding to primitives (use objects instead, for instance - $scope.data). So I'd replace `levels` to `data.levels`

It's up to you where you really need `getdata()` call, but controller's initialisation might be a better choice.

Also, if you want to keep your View clean of data, try to declare default value in model (or in service), not in View.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is one of the good way.

I have another way with some custom coding .

Here is a code for my sample.

### Html code

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label for="companyName">Tenants</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="selectedTenant" 
             required ng-options="i.CompanyName for i in tenants">
            </select>
        </div>
```

### Angular Code

```
$http.get('/tenants')
               .success(function (response) {
                   response.push({ CompanyName: "Select", TenantId: 0 });
                   $scope.tenants = response;
                   $scope.selectedTenant = response[$scope.tenants.length - 1];
                   $scope.$apply();
               })
```